# Time-dependent Schrödinger equation and density plot

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, physics

I'm interested in the density plot of the solution of a 1D time-dependent Schrödinger equation with a given potential. So I have:

```
ψ = NDSolve[{I D[u[t, x], t] == -D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] + 
 I Sin[x] u[t, x], u[0, x] == Exp[-x^2] Exp[I x], u[t, -Pi] == u[t, Pi]}, u, {t, 0, 5}, {x, -Pi, Pi}]

DensityPlot[Evaluate[Abs[u[t, x]] /. ψ], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {t, 0, 5}, PlotPoints -> 200, Mesh -> False]
```

However, *Mathematica* spits out `NDSolve::mxsst` warning and does not return anything. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Not the answer to your question but are you sure that there is `I` in front of the potential?

Comment: @Buddha_the_Scientist  Thanks for your comment. Yes, it's a complex potential.

Comment: You did not mention that your code would return a warning.

Comment: There is this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60386/ndsolve-wave-equation-triangular-wave-pulse-inital-condition which can help. It is talking about the same error.

Comment: It tries to calculate, but nothing happens.

Comment: Try this command: `\[Psi] = NDSolve[{ 
   D[u[t, x], t] == I*D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] + Sin[x] u[t, x], 
   u[0, x] == Exp[-x^2] Exp[I x], u[t, -\[Pi]] == u[t, \[Pi]]}, 
  u, {t, 0, 5}, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MaxPoints" -> 101}}]`    Then it plots something.

Comment: @Buddha_the_Scientist Thanks, I will try that.

Comment: @Buddha_the_Scientist This is a correct solution, why not turn it into an answer?

Comment: @xzczd It is already presented in the post that I have mentioned.

Comment: @Buddha_the_Scientist It's always better to post it as an answer: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/76/1871

Comment: @xzczd Ok, I have answered it. I hope it is correct.

Comment: Your code worked for me as soon as I added `Method -> "MethodOfLines"` to `NDSolve`. It took a few minutes though.

Answer (score 1):

There is [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60386/ndsolve-wave-equation-triangular-wave-pulse-inital-condition) which is talking about the same error. Following their advice I believe this must work. Please check it and tell me if it is correct or not.

```
ψ = NDSolve[{ D[u[t, x], t] == I*D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] + Sin[x] u[t, x], 
              u[0, x] == Exp[-x^2] Exp[I x], u[t, -π] == u[t, π]}, 
            u, {t, 0, 5}, {x, -π, π}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
            "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 101}}]
```

and then your plot

```
DensityPlot[Evaluate[Abs[u[t, x]] /. ψ], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {t, 0, 5}, 
            PlotPoints -> 200, Mesh -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the condition of periodicity 'u[t, -π] == u[t, π]' is wrong. A solution with such a potential cannot be symmetric about zero. On the other hand, we do not know which method to solve is correct. We can compare  solutions

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{I D[u[t, x], t] == -D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] + 
     I Sin[x] u[t, x], u[0, x] == Exp[-(x - Pi)^2] Exp[I (x - Pi)], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[t, x], x == 2*\[Pi], 
    Function[x, x - 2*\[Pi]]]}, u, {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 2*Pi}];
sol1 = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t] == 
    I*D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] + Sin[x] u[t, x], 
   u[0, x] == Exp[-(x - Pi)^2] Exp[I (x - Pi)], 
   u[t, 0] == u[t, 2*\[Pi]]}, u, {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 2*\[Pi]}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MaxPoints" -> 10000}}];
sol2 = NDSolveValue[{I D[u[t, x], t] == -D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] + 
     I Sin[x] u[t, x], u[0, x] == Exp[-(x - Pi)^2] Exp[I (x - Pi)], 
   u[t, 0] == u[t, 2*\[Pi]]}, u, {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 2*\[Pi]}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MaxPoints" -> 100}}]
    {DensityPlot[Abs[sol[t, x]], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, {t, 0, 5}, 
      PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
      ColorFunction -> Hue, FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}, PlotRange -> All], 
     DensityPlot[Abs[sol1[t, x]], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, {t, 0, 5}, 
      PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
      ColorFunction -> Hue, FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}, PlotRange -> All], 
     DensityPlot[Abs[sol1[t, x]], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, {t, 0, 5}, 
      PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
      ColorFunction -> Hue, FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: fig1]

Obviously, one of the methods is erroneous. But only `sol1` and `sol2` have a message `NDSolveValue::mxsst: Using maximum number of grid points 10000 allowed by the MaxPoints or MinStepSize options for independent variable x.` and `NDSolveValue::mxsst: Using maximum number of grid points 100 allowed by the MaxPoints or MinStepSize options for independent variable x.`

Comment: The result is incorrect because: 1. Since you've moved the domain to $[0,2π]$, the PDE should be modified accordingly, you forgot to modify the `I Sin[x] u[t, x]` term. 2. There's a bug in `PeriodicBoundaryCondition`: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124737/1871

Comment: @xzczd 1. It is possible that the condition of periodicity `u[t, -π] == u[t, π]` is wrong. A solution with such a potential cannot be symmetric about zero. 2. We can compare two solutions.

Comment: The `mxsst` warning can be eliminated with e.g. `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 200, 
    "MinPoints" -> 200, "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}`, and the solution still looks the same.

Comment: @xzczd I agree with the use of the method "MethodOfLines",  but the condition u[t, -π] == u[t, π] is obviously erroneous. It should also be understood why the first method does not agree with the second.

Comment: I've started a new question for the inconsistency between `FiniteElement` and `TensorProductGrid`: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/188109/1871