# Warnings using NDSolve on wave PDE. "Using maximum number of grid points" , "Warning: scaled local spatial error estimate"

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

Version 12 on windows 10.

I can't figure what should be changed in this call to `NDSolve` to make it happy.

This PDE is solved by `DSolve`, but `NDSolve` gives many warnings. and when trying to plot the solution it gives after long time, `Manipulate` just aborts, as each step takes very long time. So there is something wrong in the solution due to these warnings.

This wave PDE is standard one, on rectangle, all 4 edges are fixed, with initial position and zero initial velocity.

```
ClearAll[t, U, x, y]; 
L = 2; (*x dimension*)
H = 3; (*y dimension*)
c = 0.3; (*wave speed*)
f1[x_?NumericQ] := Piecewise[{{x, 0 <= x <= L/2}, {L - x, L/2 < x <= L}}];
f2[y_?NumericQ] := Piecewise[{{y, 0 <= y <= H/2}, {H - y, H/2 < y <= H}}];
pde = D[U[x, y, t], {t, 2}] == c^2*Laplacian[U[x, y, t], {x, y}];
ic = {U[x, y, 0] == f1[x]*f2[y], Derivative[0, 0, 1][U][x, y, 0] == 0};
bc = {U[x, 0, t] == 0, U[0, y, t] == 0, U[L, y, t] == 0, U[x, H, t] == 0};
numericalSol = First@NDSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, U, {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, H}, {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image]

Even though Manipulate shows the initial position correctly, it is very slow to play. Each steps takes for ever to move.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I tried using these options as suggested in comment [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60386/ndsolve-wave-equation-triangular-wave-pulse-inital-condition)

```
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 101}}
```

And tried increasing the "MaxPoints", but they had no effect. I think `NDSolve` does not like something about the initial position above, given using `Piecewise` but I see nothing wrong with it:

```
 Plot3D[f1[x]*f2[y], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, H}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is the Manipulate code which is meant to play the solution over time if needed

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[{Evaluate[U[x, y, t] /. numericalSol]}, {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, H},
  BaseStyle -> 15,
  ImageMargins -> 5,
  Mesh -> 25,
  PerformanceGoal -> "Speed",
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.4},
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-1, 1.4}},
  ImageSize -> 500,
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 1}}],
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "U(r,0)"},
  SphericalRegion -> True,
  ViewPoint -> {0.796 , -2.725 , 0.5471}
  ],
 {{t, 0, "time"}, 0, 20, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

Any suggestions what to change in the call to `NDSolve` above to remove these warnings and Make manipulate work better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try "FiniteElement" as spatial discretization

```
u = NDSolveValue[{pde, ic, bc}, U, {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, H}, {t, 0, 20}, 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t,"SpatialDiscretization" ->"FiniteElement"}]
```

which evaluates the solution without error message.

```
Manipulate[Plot3D[u[x, y, t], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, H}], {{t, 0}, 0, 20,Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If the Manipulate speed is important, you may want to have more control over your discretization.  The following creates a mesh with refinement at the center to capture the initial condition.

```
ClearAll[t, U, x, y];
L = 2;(*x dimension*)
H = 3;(*y dimension*)
c = 0.3;(*wave speed*)
f1[x_?NumericQ] := 
 Piecewise[{{x, 0 <= x <= L/2}, {L - x, L/2 < x <= L}}];
f2[y_?NumericQ] := 
  Piecewise[{{y, 0 <= y <= H/2}, {H - y, H/2 < y <= H}}];
(* Define Some Meshing Constants *)
ht = 3;
len = 2;
top = ht;
bot = 0;
left = 0;
right = len;
regs = <|domain -> 10|>;
(* Import Meshing Package *)
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
(* Set up boundary mesh *)
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{left, bot}(*1*), {right, bot}(*2*), {right, 
      top}(*3*), {left, top}(*4*)}, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}(*bottom edge*)(*1*), {4,
         1}(*left edge*)(*2*), {2, 3}(*3*), {3, 4}(*4*)}, {3, 3, 3, 
       3}]}];
bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Blue, 
   "MeshElementStyle" -> {Green, Red, Black}, ImageSize -> Large]];
(* Set up region mesh with refinement at mid point *)
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, 
   "RegionMarker" -> {{{(left + right)/2, (bot + top)/2}, 
      regs[domain], 0.004}}, 
   MeshRefinementFunction -> 
    Function[{vertices, area}, 
     area > 0.001 (0.1 + 10 Norm[(Mean[vertices] - {L/2, H/2})])]];
mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> {FaceForm[Red]}, 
  ImageSize -> Large]]
```

[image: Refined Mesh]

With FEM, there are reasonable defaults so you don't need to specify everything.  Here is how I recast your system to operate on the mesh.

```
(* Set up and solve system *)
eqn = D[U[t, x, y], t] - c^2 Laplacian[U[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 0;
dc = DirichletCondition[U[t, x, y] == 0, ElementMarker == 3];
ic = U[0, x, y] == f1[x]*f2[y];
ufunHeat = 
  NDSolveValue[{eqn, dc, ic}, U, {t, 0, 20}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];
```

When we execute Manipulate, it is reasonably fast, but you can coarsen and refine the mesh to improve performance.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[ufunHeat[t, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] ufunHeat["ElementMesh"], 
  BaseStyle -> 15, ImageMargins -> 5, Mesh -> 25, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.4}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-1, 1.5}}, ImageSize -> 500, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 1}}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "U(r,0)"}, SphericalRegion -> True, 
  ViewPoint -> {0.796, -2.725, 0.5471}], {{t, 0, "time"}, 0, 2, .01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: Manipulate animation]